# php function in html link

Tags: php, html, function, hyperlink

I am attempting to call a website root by using a PHP function within a HTML link.

I have created the function bloginfo() below and the correct link output is http://www.example.com/subdirectory/file.php.

The two methods of calling the function are similar but **method 1 does not work** and **method 2 works**.

Please can somebody explain why method 1 does not work and suggest a solution.  Thanks.

```
<?php
function bloginfo($show) {
switch ($show) {
    case 'template_url':
        echo "www.example.co.uk";
        break;
}
}

// Method 1 - does not work
echo "<a href=\"http://<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>";

?>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Method 2 - works! -->
<a href="http://<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/subdirectory/file.php">test link 2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

```
echo "<a href=\"http://".bloginfo('template_url')."/subdirectory/file.php\">
```

Thanks for your help everyone.  Unfortunately I could not get the common answer (above line of code) to work as for some reason 'www.example.com' would be printed but not as a link, and the link direction simply became '/subdirectory/file.php'.

To solve the problem I gave up on incorporating a function and decided to simply use the PHP Define method below which works for both methods.

```
<?php

//this line of code can be put into an external PHP file and called using the PHP Include method.
define("URL", "www.example.com", true);

// Method 1 - works!
echo "<a href=\"http://".URL."/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>";

?>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Method 2 - works! -->
<a href="http://<?php echo URL; ?>/subdirectory/file.php">test link 2</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double quoted string is making your php block in the first method just a plain old text string. Try this:

```
  echo "<a href=\"http://".bloginfo('template_url')."/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've nested some php tags

```
echo "<a href=\"http://" .bloginfo('template_url') . "/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://{bloginfo('template_url')}/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>";
```

Comment: oops! sorry then! my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It was because you were using  within  tags and not telling it to echo either. The below code will work - I have commented out your old line and added a new line that will work

```
<?php
function bloginfo($show) {
  switch ($show) {
    case 'template_url':
    echo "www.example.co.uk";
    break;
  }
}

// Method 1 - does not work
//echo "<a href=\"http://<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>";

echo "<a href=\"http://".bloginfo('template_url')."/subdirectory/file.php\">test link 1</a>"; <--- changed the above line to this... now both this and the lower line work


?>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Method 2 - works! -->
<a href="http://<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/subdirectory/file.php">test link 2</a>

</body>
</html>
```